# Clean Architecture diagram

Tags: architecture, diagram, clean-architecture

Below is the classical Clean Architecture diagram from Uncle Bobs [original blog post](https://8thlight.com/blog/uncle-bob/2012/08/13/the-clean-architecture.html).

[image: Clean Architecture]

I am rather confused as to why the Gateways are more outwards than the Use Cases. This is something present in all such diagrams I have seen so far that include Gateways or some other form of Data Access mechanism.

I understand that Use Cases should not bind to the specifics of the Data Access mechanism, as these should be hidden behind an architectural boundary. At the same time the only users of the services that form this boundary should be the Use Cases. That clashes hard with the diagram, as following the visual rules, Use Cases cannot use the Gateways (while they need to) and frameworky-stuff can use them (while it should not).

Am I missing something? And if not, is there a more correct way to represent the rules of The Clean Architecture visually?

I'm asking because I am creating a diagram that shows The Clean Architecture + DDD Bounded Contexts.

[image]

I'm not happy with how the DB and services bits are outside of the UseCase circle as like that it is not clear the UseCases are the public interface of the Bounded Context and that the persistence is not directly accessible from the outside.

Something like this solves these two issues but introduces a new one: no indication of the data access layer boundary. In fact, following the visual rules, the diagram suggests that everything in the Bounded Context can directly access the persistence.

[image]

I believe I am running into the same problem that causes the Gateways to be "misplaced" in the original diagram and am looking for a way around that.

Comment: I ended up putting the DB outside of the UC circle. Like this it is not super obvious the UCs form the public interface of the BC, but at least the dependencies are clear. https://www.entropywins.wtf/blog/2018/09/09/clean-architecture-bounded-contexts-diagram/

Answer (score 7):

The diagram shows where the implementations reside, not the interfaces. The gateway interfaces reside with the use cases.

Comment: That solves "UseCases need to be able to access the gateways" though leaves open "Gateway implementations should not be able to use UseCases". Or should they?

Comment: @JeroenDeDauw You could always separate the interfaces in their own module to avoid use cases being visible. However, somewhere in your application you will always be able to access all public types, hence you have the option of writing "spaghetti code". But should you? IMO. some "encapsulation" have to be enforced by convetion rather than compiler support.

Comment: @Lars-Erik my question is purely about the diagram and visual representation of the architectural rules. So not about how to follow these rules in a codebase.

Comment: Here is a quote from the book "Clean Architecture by Robert C. Martin": "Between the use case interactors and the database are the database gateways. These gateways are polymorphic interfaces that contain methods for every create, read, update, or delete operation that can be performed by the application
on the database. ...Those gateways are implemented by
classes in the database layer."
Between "use cases and the database" is the "interface adapters". So book clearly says that gateway interfaces are in the "interface adapters" layer and are implemented in the "frameworks & drivers" layer.

Answer (score 1):

The diagram is a more elaborate version of Alistair Cockburn's [Hexagonal Architecture](http://alistair.cockburn.us/Hexagonal+architecture), which is a lot more precise about the use of adapters, especially in respect to CDI.

Essentially, the idea is to turn dependencies inward: Use Cases may depend upon Entities (i.e., import domain related packages and use domain data types; Cockburn does not describe these as separate circles, but rather as "the application"). Adapters on the left may call Use Cases (i.e., *execute* or abort them, e.g. using the Command pattern), while Use Cases in turn may call *interfaces* (such as service or repository facades, which are implemented by Adapters on the right), using the principle of Dependency Inversion to preserve the inbound direction.

If you're confused about "left" and "right": In Cockburn's picture, the hexagon has adapters on the left (input/interaction mechanisms) and on the right (persistence, external systems, services). You may think of it as a 3-layer-architecture diagram turned 90 degrees, where the domain layer does not depend on the persistence layer, but the other way around.

Again, Cockburn's explanation, while perhaps a bit harder to grasp due to the unusual hexagonal image, is the more precise one, because it doesn't try to include everything and concentrates on the dependency fundamentals.

Comment: Bob Martin's version of CQRS, "interactors and presenters" consequently also falls short, btw, as soon as one leaves the realm of server-side web applications. Architecture is never a one-size-fits-all, but a game of trade-offs, and should always be tailored to the individual problem- and solution space.

Comment: Can you explain how it falls short for applications that are not server side web-apps? (Or link to an explanation)

Comment: I've amended my question to make it more clear I am interested in how to visualize the persistence and associated adapters better in a diagram following the circle style.

Comment: To answer the follow-up: 1) In highly distributed systems, the flow of information is often multi-directional and requires "hopping in an out" of the described circles. There may be interactors or presenters involved, but there don't have to be. There are also often party of the system that contain read-only services and views (read models), and state is (re-)calculated from events. You will find some of the principles embedded in "Clean Architecture", of course, but reality will differ.

Comment: 2) In Enterprise environments, you have domain knowledge, presenter and view logic in highly partitioned, often legacy systems that will cover some of the flow of information, but can not as neatly separated as "an adapter that calls an api". It is, again, good to apply the underlying principles (e.g., strive for domain separation and well-defined anti-corruption layers with clean interfaces), but requires more fine-grained approaches to make it work.

Comment: 3) in single page apps and mobile apps, which Martin conveniently abstracts away as "devices", you will often have local domain logic and state, which has to be synchronized with the web services in this diagram. Some of the interactions may look as described, but there are more complex data flow scenarios involved. Once again, the underlying principles are useful, but the solution described by this diagram falls short.

Comment: I think it is dangerous to assume that there is only one true way of designing "Clean Architecture", and thus every other way must be "unclean". For different system components, different requirements and different environments, different rules will apply. What's prudent in one scenario may turn out to be a hindrance in others. Identifying useful patterns and principles is a good thing - but always remember that architecture is a game of tradeoffs and compromises and by its very nature decidedly non-binary.

Answer (score 1):

In your BC drawing your are missing a surrounding circle outside UC. That circle is infraestructure, where you should place the Repository implementation of the Repository interface of the Domain Model. The implementation access the DB using a technology (SQL for example).

So the circles are from inside to outside:

- Domain Model (entities, value objects, repositories(interfaces), etc)
- Application Layer (use cases).
- Infraestructure (UI,repositories(implementation),etc)

Dependencies points inwards and not just the next circle inside (infraestructure depends both on application layer and domain model).

I use hexagonal architecture though.

Comment: Given that in my diagram there can be no UI code inside of a Bounded Context, I'm not sure why the infrastructure would ever depend on the UseCases. In fact to me it seems implementations of repositories should never use a UseCase. Do you see things differently?

Comment: If you don't have UI inside your BC, then just don't put any UI component in the infraestructure circle. The infraestructure depends on the use cases because there are some application layer concerns that are implemented by the infraestrucure (transactions, security, and in general any concern that is not specific of the BC domain).Along with those concerns,in the infraestructure circle also live the implementation of domain specific interfaces (like repositories).The dependencies rules of the architecture allows you to access use cases from the implementation of repositories,but you shouldn't

Comment: It's up to the developer not to do those kind of things. But the architecture in circles I told you (onion architecture) allow to do them. That's why I prefer Ports and Adapters (aka Hexagonal Architecture).

Answer (score 0):

The gateway interfaces must reside in the use cases layer and implemented in the interface adapters layer to ensure the dependency rule.

```
  Interface Adapters Layer    || Use Cases Layer
                              ||
  +-----------------+         || <implements>    +-------------+   <uses>  +---------+
  |JDBCEntityGateway| --------++-------------->  +EntityGateway|  <------  | UseCase |
  +-----------------+         ||                 +-------------+           +---------+
                              ||
```

This pattern can be applied to every architectural boundary. The higher level layer defines an interface to tell what it needs and not how it is done. The lower level layer implements that interface and thus defines how it is done. Maybe that's why the layer is named `interface adapters`. As a result of this you can change the way of how something is done by providing another implementation. You might recognize now that this is the open-close principle.

But keep in mind that the interface should be a stable abstraction of what the use case needs. Don't put implementation specific things in that interface, e.g. if you specify a find method like this `List<Eintity> find(String where)`. Becauese the `where` string is a detail, perhaps a SQL or JPQL string part. You should rather introduce a `EntityCriteria` that describes the selection criteria in an implementation independent way.

Answer (score 0):

I find this question and the discussion under it very interesting because we have a comment from the user @RobertMartin and the fact that his answer adds more confusion than clarity.

For the sake of consistency, and keeping only one source of truth, I will not use interpretations of the clean architecture in other articles across the internet I will also ignore the answer under this question by the user with the name @RobertMartin that states that

> The diagram shows where the implementations reside, not the
> interfaces. The gateway interfaces reside with the use cases.

because it also does not match everything that was written in the book "**Clean Architecture: A Craftsman’s Guide to Software Structure and Design by Robert C. Martin (2017)**".

Taking everything above into consideration as if we had only the book I will answer the question from my point of view, my interpretation of the clean architecture that was described in the book and from my personal experience of successful use of the implementation of the "clean architecture".

Let's start with this:

> ...following the visual rules, Use Cases cannot use the Gateways (while
> they need to) and frameworky-stuff can use them (while it should not).

You know I was thinking about the same question for a week, when I tried to implement the closest implementation of the clean architecture possible, by following the description from the book word for word, because usually, you do not notice the problem until you try to decouple layers.

Let's look at some related quotes from the book, and see how it is described there:

> A use case is a description of the way that an automated system is used.
> It specifies the input to be provided by the user, the output to be
> returned to the user, and the processing steps involved in producing
> that output.

> A use case is an object. It has one or more functions that implement
> the application-specific business rules. It also has data elements
> that include the input data, the output data, and the references to
> the appropriate Entities with which it interacts. Entities have no
> knowledge of the use cases that control them.

> DATABASE GATEWAYS
>
> **Between the use case interactors and the database** are the database
> gateways. **These gateways are polymorphic interfaces** that contain
> methods for every create, read, update, or delete operation that can
> be performed by the application on the database. For example, if the
> application needs to know the last names of all the users who logged
> in yesterday, then the UserGateway interface will have a method named
> getLastNamesOfUsersWhoLoggedInAfter that takes a Date as its argument
> and returns a list of last names. Recall that we do not allow SQL in
> the use cases layer; instead, we use gateway interfaces that have
> appropriate methods. **Those gateways are implemented by classes in the
> database layer.**

What is "Between the use case interactors and the database"? Of course "Interface adapters" layer, so the book gives us an instruction on implementing a gateway interface and now we know that it should be in the interface adapters layer and implemented in the outer frameworks and drivers layer.

**But how to implement Use Cases without importing gateway interfaces from the outer interface adapters layer?**

To mitigate this issue I decided to follow a technique called "Ports and Adapters" (also known as "Hexagonal Architecture" or "Ports and Adapters Architecture"), which is an architectural pattern that can help to achieve a higher degree of separation between the inner core and the outer layers. In this pattern, the inner core defines interfaces (ports) that are implemented by the outer layers (adapters), and the dependencies flow from the inner core to the adapters, without the need for the inner core to import any specific interface from the outer layers.

I am afraid it will be hard to describe what I mean without a clear visualization, so here's an example using the Ports and Adapters pattern in the Clean Architecture in the Flutter project:

**Application Business Rules**

Use case:

```
import 'package:entities/entities.dart';

/// [GetDogsResourceUseCase] is a class with functions that have prominent
/// positions within the architecture, and they will have names that clearly
/// describe their function.
/// From the [GetDogsResourceUseCase], it is impossible to tell whether the
/// application is delivered on the web, on a thick client, or a console,
/// or is a pure service.
abstract class GetDogsResourceUseCase {
  const GetDogsResourceUseCase();

  Stream<Resource<List<Dog>>> callAsStream([Params params]);

  Future<Resource<List<Dog>>> callAsFuture([Params params]);
}
```

**Interface adapters**

Use case adapter:

```
    import 'package:dogs_app_interface_adapters/dogs_app_interface_adapters.dart';
    import 'package:dogs_app_use_cases/dogs_app_use_cases.dart';
    import 'package:entities/entities.dart';
    import 'package:injectable/injectable.dart';
    
    /// A [GetDogsResourceUseCaseAdapter] specifies the [Params]
    /// to be provided by the user, the [Resource] to be returned to the user, and
    /// the processing steps involved in producing that output [Resource].
    @Injectable(as: GetDogsResourceUseCase)
    class GetDogsResourceUseCaseAdapter implements GetDogsResourceUseCase {
      const GetDogsResourceUseCaseAdapter(this._dogsGateway);
    
      final DogsGateway _dogsGateway;
    
      @override
      Stream<Resource<List<Dog>>> callAsStream([
        Params input = const Params(),
      ]) {
    //TODO: implement
    // step 1
    //_paramsGateway.getSavedDogsAsStream,
    // step 2
    //_dogsGateway.requestDogs,
    // step 3
    //_dogsGateway.saveDogs,
}
    
      @override
      Future<Resource<List<Dog>>> callAsFuture([
        Params input = const Params(),
      ]) {
    //TODO: implement
    // step 1
    //_dogsGateway.getSavedDogsAsFuture,
    // step 2
    //_dogsGateway.requestDogs,
    // step 3
    //_dogsGateway.saveDogs,
}
```

Gateway:

```
import 'package:entities/entities.dart';

abstract class DogsGateway {
  Future<List<Dog>> requestDogs([
    Params params = const Params(),
  ]);

  Stream<List<Dog>> getSavedDogsAsStream([
    Params params = const Params(),
  ]);

  Future<List<Dog>> getSavedDogsAsFuture([
    Params params = const Params(),
  ]);

  Future<void> saveDogs(List<Dog> dogs);
}
```

**Frameworkds & Drivers**

Gateway implementation:

```
@Injectable(as: DogsGateway)
class DogsGatewayImpl implements DogsGateway {
  const DogsGatewayImpl(this._restClient, this._dogsDao);

  final RestClient _restClient;
  final DogsDao _dogsDao;

  @override
  Stream<List<Dog>> getSavedDogsAsStream([
    Params params = const Params(),
  ]) {
     //TODO: implement
     //_dogsDao.streamDogs
  }

  @override
  Future<List<Dog>> getSavedDogsAsFuture([
    Params params = const Params(),
  ]) {
    //TODO: implement
    //_dogsDao.getDogs
  }

  @override
  Future<List<Dog>> requestDogs([
    Params params = const Params(),
  ]) {
      //TODO: implement
      //_getDogsResponse(params)
  }

  @override
  Future<void> saveDogs(List<Dog> dogs) {
    // TODO: Save remote dogs in a local database
    //_dogsDao.updateDogs
  }
```

As you can see I achieved implementation of the same diagram that was presented in the book, without violating the dependency rules.

Let's move to your next question:

> Am I missing something?

I am afraid that either the book missing something or the diagram missing something and since I am writing this answer 6 years after publishing the book, and Robert C. Martin has not published an edited version of the "Clean Architecture" yet, we will have to use our imagination to think about what is best for our project and how it will better fit our needs creating our own interpretation of the clean architecutre.

And your last question:

> And if not, is there a more correct way to represent the rules of The
> Clean Architecture visually?

As a matter of fact, there is. I ended up representing the diagram more correctly, at least in a way that has practical implementation and proof of concept that it can be implemented in a real project, eliminating confusion and adding **<i>** sign where the object represents an abstract interface.

[image]